# How to get the title of a page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I set my title of the page like this in the blade view template:

```
@section('title', 'Example.com - Welcome to Example.com for all your needs')
```

This is working well. Now I want to know how can I access/print the current page title in the body part?

I mean for getting the current URL, we can use `Request::url()`. Is there a way that I can get the current page title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this in Laravel, but this is easily accomplished in Javascript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log($("title").text());
});
```

Will print the title of the current page to the console. You can assign this value to an element by targeting it's id `$("#id_of_element")` or class `$(".class_of_elemnt")` and setting the text to the title's text:

```
$("#id_of_element").text($("title").text());
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: or without jquery `window.document.title`

Comment: @zgr024 Yeah, that too, but I forget the last time I used Javascript without JQuery.

Comment: @Tim Lewis completely understandable but one can't be dependent on jQuery all of the time

Comment: Any way to assign the title to a php variable?

Comment: Dynamically through Javascript; Yes, but not in a simple way. You'd somehow have to `POST` the title to the server using a form and Javascript `.submit` function and pick it up in php with the `$_POST` array. If the page title is stored in a database or somewhere where it can fetched by either a Query in PHP or AJAX in Javascript, then this would be easy.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not a good idea to set the page title with hard code in layout file.
one of the best ways is to have a default page title in layout and override it in every view page.
just like below :

layout title :: {{ isset($title) ? $title : 'page title' }}

Answer (score 1):

You can print your page title using

```
@yield('title)
```

wherever you want.